# Different result for same query executed by Web application and by Access 2007 query wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, oledb

I am executing following query from my web application and access 2007 query wizard. And I am getting two different result.

Access Query Wizard Query:

```
SELECT
    R.RId,
    R.RNo,
    R.CustId,
    R.WingId,
    R.FloorId,
    R.FlatId,
    FORMAT( R.Rdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) AS Rdate,
    R.Amount,
    C.CustName,
    ( W.Wname + '-' + F.FlatNo ) AS FlatNo,
    Fl.FloorName,
    F.TotalCost,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM( r.Amount )
        FROM
            tblReceipt As r
        WHERE
            r.FlatId = F.FlatId
        GROUP BY
            r.FlatId
     ) AS ReceivedAmt
FROM
    tblFlat AS F
    INNER JOIN (
        tblFloor AS Fl
        INNER JOIN (
            tblWing As W
            INNER JOIN (
                blCust As C
                INNER JOIN tblReceipt As R ON C.CustId = R.CustId
            ) ON W.WingId = R.WingId
        ) ON Fl.FloorId = R.FloorId
    ) ON F.FlatId = R.FlatId
```

C# Code :

```
public DataTable getReceipts(int cmpid)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(getConnection()))
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText =  "SELECT " +
    "R.RId," +
    "R.RNo,"+
    "R.CustId,"+
    "R.WingId,"+
    "R.FloorId,"+
    "R.FlatId,"+
    "FORMAT( R.Rdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) AS Rdate,"+
    "R.Amount,"+
    "C.CustName,"+
    "( W.Wname + '-' + F.FlatNo ) AS FlatNo,"+
    "Fl.FloorName,"+
    "F.TotalCost,"+
    "("+
     "   SELECT"+
      "      SUM( r.Amount )"+
       " FROM"+
        "    tblReceipt As r"+
        "WHERE"+
         "   r.FlatId = F.FlatId"+
        "GROUP BY"+
         "   r.FlatId"+
     ") AS ReceivedAmt"+
"FROM"+
"    tblFlat AS F"+
 "   INNER JOIN ("+
  "      tblFloor AS Fl"+
   "     INNER JOIN ("+
    "        tblWing As W"+
     "       INNER JOIN ("+
      "          blCust As C"+
       "         INNER JOIN tblReceipt As R ON C.CustId = R.CustId"+
        "    ) ON W.WingId = R.WingId"+
        ") ON Fl.FloorId = R.FloorId"+
    ") ON F.FlatId = R.FlatId ";

            conn.Open();

            using (OleDbDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (sdr.HasRows)
                    dt.Load(sdr);
            }

        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

When I execute this query from access query wizard I get aggregate value for "ReceivedAmt" column which is correct, but running from web application it does not aggregate value for "ReceivedAmt" column.I do not know how I am getting different result for exact same query.If any information missing please comment. I stuck here....please help..

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not aggregate value"? What kind of actual results do you get?

Comment: @Dai :  "it does not aggregate value" means by running query from application  the column "ReceivedAmt"(Alias column for sum of Amount) not aggregated , whereas its aggregate value when running from Access query wizard. And query is (exact)same for both scenario.

Comment: Show the C# code please

Comment: can't see "cmpid" as parameter in c# code!!!

Comment: @H.Mahida: sorry it was mistake in C# code..